# How to fix endless reboot loop installing Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 - message: A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes

Tags: windows-10, odbc, ssms

Installing Microsoft® ODBC Driver 17 on windows 10.
During the install, Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server setup stops and shows "A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer then run Setup again. 
rebooted but not fixed.
4 reboots and then tried install again.  Same issue.

Microsoft ODBC 13 driver installs and uninstalls without any issues.

I've reviewed Microsoft support site and found nothing that describes this issue.
  There are notes about odbc 13 and 17 causing conflict.  odbc 13 is not installed.

[checked this potential](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2008982/you-are-repeatedly-prompted-to-restart-the-computer-when-installing-sq) for SQL Server install requiring reboots, but nothing in my registry for PendingFileRenameOperations.

Has anyone found the clue that Driver 17 is using to think it needs another reboot to continue?  I need to get SSMS installed and it has a dependency on ODBC Driver 17.

windows 10 updated to current.
doing install as admin.

Comment: I already checked for issues noted in "You are repeatedly prompted to restart the computer when installing SQL Server 2008".  No PendingFileRenameOperations.

Comment: [microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-fix-endless-reboot-loop-installing/00bc6cf7-2af8-495d-8f2b-c93d3f6b8cda?messageId=15659e07-dd94-4f89-a209-94df7edeb667) suggesting use the tool below to uninstall/install that driver
[microsoft windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed).  did not resolve my issue.  the odbc driver isn't found by the tool and didn't identify issue to fix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used the tool at the following url to uninstall/install the driver ODBC 17 driver (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed).  I needed to copy/paste the product code below to uninstall the ODBC 17 driver. {12DC69AF-787B-4D76-B69D-2716DACA79FB}

After reboot, I was able to successfully install ODBC 17 driver.

Answer (score 81):

I have found one another solution under https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9pq3fUOO3s that worked for me when I faced problems with ODBC Driver 17 installation while updating
Microsoft SQL Server.

It basically requires cleaning  the value of `PendingFileRenameOperations` (replacing the multi-string value with an empty string) under the registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`.

[image]

You might also like to consider the analysis from [@oopoopoop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5756053/oopoopoop) that is posted here as another answer to this question.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me (actually installing SQL Server Management Studio, that installs ODBC 17), thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too, Win10 + SSMS 18.8, thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for me. I'm actually installing Sql Server 2019, which apparently also installs ODBC Driver 17, so I think my case is similar to @bobroxsox .

Comment: This works but answer not clear as to exactly how to update the registry item.

Comment: If that registry item `PendingFileRenameOperations` does not exist, should it be created? There is one called `FileRenameOperations` on my Windows10 x64 PC.

Comment: @Tim I believe you incorrectly check the key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\FileRenameOperations` when you should be checking for the value `PendingFileRenameOperations` directly under the key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`. Screenshot added.

Comment: @olin000: Thank you.

Comment: Works perfectly with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with Azure Data Studio Release 18.12.1

Comment: Worked for me!!  SSMS 19 Preview and Windows 11

Comment: This works also for ODBC 18

Answer (score 4):

The ODBC driver might be already installed when installing the Visual Studio.
Find it in the installed applications and uninstall it.
Then run the SSMS installer. It will finish without error and install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [olin000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12496708/olin000)'s answer, which guided me to the correct registry key / value.

Like some of you, however, I was not sure if I should simply remove all 'Pending File Rename Operations'. Doing this makes it sound like I will have a bunch of obsolete files in my PC that will be forgotten forever. So I decided to go just a tad deeper into the issue.

### The check

Below is the first set of files in my `PendingFileRenameOperations` under the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`:

```
\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\vcruntime140_1.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\vcruntime140.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\streamserver.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\repoman.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\officeclicktorun.exe

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\msvcp140.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\msix.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\concrt140.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660\apiclient.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20660

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\vcruntime140_1.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\vcruntime140.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\repoman.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\msvcp140.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\msix.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\concrt140.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvpolicy.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvorchestration.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvmanifest.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvisvvirtualization.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvisvsubsystemcontroller.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvisvstreamingmanager.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvisvapi.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvintegration.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvfilesystemmetadata.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\appvcatalog.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626\apiclient.dll

\??\c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\updates\16.0.15601.20626

\??\C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\Updates
```

They definitely look related to 'Click-to-Run' with a 'clicktorun' path. After doing some search...

### What to do

I ended up manually stopping the 'Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service' temporarily, delete those related files, let my PC restart a final time.

A second look after the reboot at the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`, the value `PendingFileRenameOperations` is gone. This mean that the rest of the files in the value had all been taken care of by simply restarting.

As you would have guessed by now, the installation went smoothly afterwards.

### Just a reminder

for people who want to manually handling stuck operations in value `PendingFileRenameOperations`. Do remember that there are two kinds of 'operations'. Delete or Rename. Each of them is represented by two lines. A 'Delete' is a line with the filename plus an empty line to follow. A 'Rename' is a line with the old filename plus a line with the new filename.

Using the below as an example.

```
\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\New\PrintConfig.dll
\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\PrintConfig.dll
\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\New\PrintConfig.dll
\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\PrintConfig.dll
\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\drivers\x64\3\Old\1\PrintConfig.dll
```

- Rename W32X86\3\New\PrintConfig.dll to W32X86\3\PrintConfig.dll
- Rename x64\3\New\PrintConfig.dll to x64\3\PrintConfig.dll
- Delete x64\3\Old\1\PrintConfig.dll